# EF Core works with razor pages but not MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

So I am working on my application and for some reason anything to do with the UserManager, RoleManager, and SigninManager will not work in views and controllers.  It tells me that it cannot access the database.  I'm guessing it is a context issue.  The migrations work fine and I can create objects in the database outside of the identity system. If I use the scaffolding to override pages in auth/identity using razor pages, all works fine (registration, login, etc).  When I try to check for a role just as a test it in one of my view actions to a controller it gives me the following error:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection: Error: An error occurred using the connection to database 'DDDTemplate' on server '.'.
```

It is a local database setup with trusted connections on SQL server.

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        _env = env;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddApplication();
        services.AddInfrastructure(Configuration);
        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        services.AddSingleton<ICurrentUserService, CurrentUserService>();

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        services.AddControllersWithViews()
                .AddFluentValidation();

        //services.AddRazorPages();

        if (_env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IConsoleLogger, ConsoleLogger>();
            
        }
        else
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IConsoleLogger, NullConsoleLogger>();
        }
        
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            Routes.Addroutes(endpoints);
        });
    }
}
```

**Routes.cs**

```
public static class Routes
{

    public static void Addroutes(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        //endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    }
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "UseInMemoryDatabase": false,
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DDDTemplate;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

**AccountController.cs**

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> _roleManager;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly IIdentityService _identityService;

    public AccountController(RoleManager<ApplicationRole> RoleManager, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, IIdentityService identityService)
    {
        _roleManager = RoleManager;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _identityService = identityService;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Login(string t)
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Register(RegisterViewModel userInfo)
    {

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async void Login(LoginViewModel loginInfo)
    {
        try
        {

            bool x = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin");
            Console.WriteLine("test");

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
           
        }
        
    }
}
```

**Login.cshtml** from Views/Account folder

```
@model DDDTemplate.App.LoginViewModel
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using DDDTemplate.Data.Identity
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
@inject RoleManager<ApplicationRole> RoleManager
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
}
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Register Account</h1>
    <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"></div>
        <div>
            <label asp-for="Username"></label>
            <input asp-for="Username" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Username"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label asp-for="Password"></label>
            <input asp-for="Password" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Password"></span>
        </div>

        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**In a dependency Injection file in a referenced project called during services configure**

```
public static IServiceCollection AddInfrastructure(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(
            configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
            b =>
                b.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext).Assembly.FullName)
        )
    );

    services
        .AddIdentity<ApplicationUser,ApplicationRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultUI()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders(); ;

    services.AddScoped<IApplicationDbContext>(provider => provider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>());

    services.AddScoped<IDomainEventService, DomainEventService>();

    services.AddTransient<IDateTime, DateTimeService>();
    services.AddTransient<IIdentityService, IdentityService>();
    services.AddTransient<ICsvFileBuilder, CsvFileBuilder>();

    services.AddAuthorization();

    return services;
}
```

**ApplicationDBContext.cs**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>, IApplicationDbContext
{

    private IDomainEventService _domainEventService {get;}
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, IDomainEventService domainEventService) : base(options)
    {
        _domainEventService = domainEventService;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ApplicationDbContext)));
        
    }

    public DbSet<TodoItem> TodoItems { get; set; }

    public DbSet<TodoList> TodoLists { get; set; }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        foreach (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.EntityEntry<AuditableEntity> entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<AuditableEntity>())
        {
            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    entry.Entity.CreatedBy = _currentUserService.;
                    entry.Entity.Created = _dateTime.Now;
                    break;

                case EntityState.Modified:
                    entry.Entity.LastModifiedBy = _currentUserService.UserId;
                    entry.Entity.LastModified = _dateTime.Now;
                    break;
            }
        }

        var result = await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);

        await DispatchEvents();

        return result;
    }

    private async Task DispatchEvents()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var domainEventEntity = ChangeTracker.Entries<IHasDomainEvent>()
                .Select(x => x.Entity.DomainEvents)
                .SelectMany(x => x)
                .Where(domainEvent => !domainEvent.IsPublished)
                .FirstOrDefault();
            if (domainEventEntity == null) break;

            domainEventEntity.IsPublished = true;
            await _domainEventService.Publish(domainEventEntity);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing to check would be the user account the application pool is running as if this is running in IIS.

Comment: @StevePy would that be an issue if I can execute CRUD with other none identity models just fine? They are all using the same database context.

Comment: Hi @ObieMD5, Is there any detail error message? From your description, the scaffolding  Identity razor pages (such as register and login) works well, as we all known, these pages  also using UserManager or RoleManager, please check them if there have any different or not? Besides, in the Account Login page (index.cshtml), I think there is no need to add the inject for SignInManager, UserManager or SignInManager, try to remove them. And in the Account controller, there have a IIdentityService, not sure whether the issue is related it or not. You can check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem was that I was returning void from an async function that had a task.  There are only certain instances that is acceptable, this was not one of them.  So on **AccountController.cs** I changed the following to return Task instead of void and everything is working correctly:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task Login(LoginViewModel loginInfo)
    {
        try
        {

            bool x = await _roleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin");
            Console.WriteLine("test");

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
           
        }
        
    }
```